# After brew/ddev upgrade (Colima), I can't start ddev (out of space, images and volumes lost)

Tags: docker, ddev, colima

I use Colima with DDEV and I ran the brew update and upgrade command and it updated ddev. After that, when I run 'ddev start' on my local, it starts downloading the ddev-webserver and after that it gives me the following error:

`e54debc59c92: Extracting [==================================================>]  383.6MB/383.6MB failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /var/tmp/backdrop_drush_commands/backdrop-drush-extension/commands/pm/backdrop_pm_enable.drush.inc: no space left on device failed to RunSimpleContainer to inspect database version/type: failed to pull image drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.3: exit status 1, output=`

I have a lot of space free on my mac. When I run 'df -H' it gives me:

`Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on /dev/disk3s3s1   494G    15G   331G     5%  502080 3227540360    0%   / devfs            205k   205k     0B   100%     694          0  100%   /dev /dev/disk3s6     494G    20k   331G     1%       0 3227540360    0%   /System/Volumes/VM /dev/disk3s4     494G   414M   331G     1%     776 3227540360    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot /dev/disk3s2     494G    61M   331G     1%      22 3227540360    0%   /System/Volumes/Update /dev/disk1s2     524M   6.3M   503M     2%       1    4914040    0%   /System/Volumes/xarts /dev/disk1s1     524M   7.7M   503M     2%      32    4914040    0%   /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot /dev/disk1s3     524M   2.1M   503M     1%      48    4914040    0%   /System/Volumes/Hardware /dev/disk3s1     494G   147G   331G    31% 1656317 3227540360    0%   /System/Volumes/Data map auto_home      0B     0B     0B   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home map -fstab         0B     0B     0B   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/Network/Servers`

When I run 'docker system df' it gives me the following:

`TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE Images          0         0         0B        0B Containers      0         0         0B        0B Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B`

Please help, I do not know what is wrong or what to do to fix this.

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop?  That has a hidden VM with its own disk space, and you can either increase the disk size in the "whale" application or use commands like `docker system prune` to free up space in the Docker environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze No, I'm using Colima instead of Docker Desktop. But Randy answered me that Colima has an issue on it's latest release and since then it's been fixed and updated and now all is working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a regression in Lima v0.14.0, which you unwittingly updated. It has been fixed in Lima v0.14.1, which you can get with `brew update && brew upgrade lima` and you should be fine again.

- https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/506
- https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/issues/1242

Comment: Fantastic! This worked!

Thank you Randy for your feedback. I really appreciate it.